# Does the wc command strip the trailing line feed from txt files?

Tags: command-line, terminal, wc

I'm currently building a replica of the `wc` command line call (in C). I have a file [tst.txt][image: tst.txt]
and the C code to read that file. The `wc tst.txt` command responds with the output: `2       6      20 tst.txt`, meaning 2 line feeds ('\n'). My code, however, counts 3 line feeds. I am assuming this is due to the *systematic* trailing new line at the end of the file (following Line 3).

Am I correct in thinking that the `wc` command strips the trailing line feed (by trailing I mean at the EOF), or is a piece of my code incorrect?

Could be that I am incrementing an extra unit?

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkForNewLine(char* line, int lineSize); 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // declare variables
    FILE *inputFile;                        // pointer to inputted file
    inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");        // set input file to 2nd cmd-line arg.
    int newLineCount = 0;
    int newLineIncr = 0;

    // if file is not found
    if (inputFile == NULL){
        printf("%s", "File not found\n");
        return (-1);                        // end program
    }

    char line[201];                         // set line to 200 char MAX. 


    while (fgets(line, 201, inputFile) != NULL){

        // new line count
        newLineCount = newLineCount + checkForNewLine(line, 201); 
    } 
    if (feof(inputFile)) {
    } 
    else {
        printf("%s", "Some Other Error...");
    }

    printf("New Line Count [%d]\n", (newLineCount));

    fclose(inputFile);

}

int checkForNewLine(char *line, int lineSize){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lineSize; i++) {
        if (line[i] == '\0'){
            count++;
            printf("count amount: %d\n", count);
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the great answer below, let's emphasize what mainstream `wc`'s documentation says that it prints the "newline count", and indeed it does exactly that.

Answer (score 5):

From [`man 3 fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html):

```
The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array
pointed to by s, until n−1 bytes are read, or a <newline> is read and
transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered.
```

So your code counts the last line, *irrespective of whether it had a newline at the end of it* (which it doesn't), because EOF was encountered. After all, the `checkForNewLine()` function is checking for, well, null characters, not newlines. Use `od`, `hexdump`, etc. to verify what the last character of your input file is.